# To have Bash to do case insensitive operation on a test

Tags: bash, case-insensitive

How to have Bash to do case insensitive operation on test:

```
$ n=Foo
$ [ -e "$n" ] && echo $n exist

foo exist
```

if it is:

```
$ ls
foo   bar   baz
```

How the correct setting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use bash case insensitive global matching pattern :

```sh
$ shopt -s nocaseglob
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ n=Foo
$ f=("$n"*)
$ [ "${f[0]/$n/}" = "" ] && echo ${f[0]} exist
foo exist
```

But take care that to have a conditional test matching a **pattern** and not directly a filename with `f=("$n"*)`, we use here a `*`.  With that, you'll get a wrong result if there is pattern symbols like `*` or `?` in `$n`.

You have also to carefully consider the *global* effect of shell options (`shopt -s nocaseglob`, `shopt -s nocasematch`). Generally, to avoid unexpected behaviors in any following shell commands / scripts, you have to restore initial states of theses options. Check and store the initial state with shopt *option* to restore it later.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ipath` in `find`.

```
if tmp=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -ipath "./$n") && [[ -n "$tmp" ]]; then
   echo "$n exists and there are:" $tmp
fi
```